# Vector to matrix in Octave

Tags: octave

What is the inverse operation to `vec` in Octave?

E.g. if I need to convert 12x1 vector into 3x4 matrix, what should I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know Octave, but I think you're looking for [`reshape`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Rearranging-Matrices.html#doc%2dreshape).

> — Built-in Function: **reshape** (*A, m, n, ...*)
>   — Built-in
>   Function: **reshape** (*A,* [*m n ...*])
>   — Built-in Function:
>   **reshape** (*A, ...,* []*, ...*)
>   — Built-in Function: **reshape** (*A, size*)
>
> Return a matrix with the specified dimensions (*m, n, ...*) whose elements are taken from the matrix A. The elements of the matrix are accessed in column-major order (like Fortran arrays are stored).
>
> The following code demonstrates reshaping a 1x4 row vector into a 2x2 square matrix.
>
> ```
>       reshape ([1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 2)
>            ⇒  1  3
>                2  4
> ```
>
> Note that the total number of elements in the original matrix (`prod (size (A))`) must match the total number of elements in the new matrix (`prod ([`*m n ...*`])`).
>
> A single dimension of the return matrix may be left unspecified and Octave will determine its size automatically. An empty matrix ([]) is used to flag the unspecified dimension.

Comment: `The elements of the matrix are accessed in column-major order (like Fortran arrays are stored).` What if I need the values to be placed in row-major order?

Comment: @Andre: Place them in column-major order first, then transpose the matrix (using postfix operator `.'`). You cannot do this operation without copying the data.

Comment: @Andre [This works in Matlab](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/22515-reshape-columnwise-any-command-to-linewise#answer_29626), should also work in Octave.